# Azure Data Factory - Teams Message Card including variable results

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, webhooks

I have a teams message card that I post using a web activity.

Currently, I do a lookup to determine whether or not I post the results, those results are stored in a variable, like so;

[image]

I want to include the results held in "Set variable" within my teams message, this will output the following as an array;

[image]

Using the web body, in expression builder, how can I include the values stored in the variable within my message, here is what I have generated so far;

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"summary": "This is the summary property",
"themeColor": "800000",
"sections": [
    {
        "heroImage": {
            "image": "https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/FlowLogo.png"
        }
    },
    {
        "startGroup": true,
        "title": "**Checks - Requires Investigation**",
        "facts": [
            {
                "name": "Date submitted:",
                "value": "06/27/2017, 2:44 PM"
            },
            {
                "name": "Details:",
                "value": "The validation checks are hilighted below; "
            },
            {
                "name": "Results:",
                "value": "Include the output here"
            },
            {
                "name": "Support Document:",
                "value": "[Click here](https://dev.azure.com/supportDocument)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String interpolation` to include the value of your variable (array). Please look at the following demonstration:

- I have used a fake API in my web activity where I use `PUT` method. The following is the request body that is needed to be passed to the API.

```
{
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader"
}
```

- Instead of using static data, if I want to use dynamic content (lets say, for 'name') i.e., use the result of my variable in the web body, we can do it in the following way. In the following, the variable `req_name` has value `morpheus`.

```
{
"name": "@{variables('req_name')}",
"job": "leader"
}
```

[image]

- Now since you have the required result, which should be used in web body, stored in your variable, you can change your body as follows in the expression builder:

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"summary": "This is the summary property",
"themeColor": "800000",
"sections": [
    {
        "heroImage": {
            "image": "https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/FlowLogo.png"
        }
    },
    {
        "startGroup": true,
        "title": "**Checks - Requires Investigation**",
        "facts": [
            {
                "name": "Date submitted:",
                "value": "06/27/2017, 2:44 PM"
            },
            {
                "name": "Details:",
                "value": "The validation checks are hilighted below; "
            },
            {
                "name": "Results:",
                "value": "@{variables('<your_variable_name>')}"
            },
            {
                "name": "Support Document:",
                "value": "[Click here](https://dev.azure.com/supportDocument)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**NOTE:**

- You can always check the [debug input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Z5p.png) to check whether the body you are passing is the correct format.
- If it is not, then you can manipulate the variable as required to convert it to required format and then include its value as demonstrated above using **String Interpolation** (@{......}).